# Creating from jmh archetype fails with NoClassDefFoundError for commons-lang StringUtils class

Tags: java, maven, jmh

I've used JMH in the past, and I've always started from the archetype.  Today, I just ran

> mvn archetype:generate -DinteractiveMode=false -DarchetypeGroupId=org.openjdk.jmh -DarchetypeArtifactId=jmh-java-benchmark-archetype -DgroupId=com.example -DartifactId=jmhBenchmarks -Dversion=1.0

This ran for quite a while, emitting log messages about attempts to download artifacts.  I was only paying half attention to it while it ran.  I then noticed that the output looked like stacktraces.  I paged back up to the top and found the first point where it started complaining, and I saw this:

> [WARNING] Error initializing: org.codehaus.plexus.velocity.DefaultVelocityComponent@57d0fc89
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils
>       at org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl.initialize (ResourceManagerImpl.java:161)
>       at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.initializeResourceManager (RuntimeInstance.java:730)

Followed by the rest of a very long stacktrace.  This was followed by what appeared to be many duplicates of the same stack trace.

I don't know if it matters, but I don't have commons-lang in my local maven repo.  I do have commons-lang3, however.

Comment: please show the example project best would be a reference to a github/bitbucket etc. project...

Comment: I don't HAVE a project.  That is the point.  All I've done here is attempt to CREATE a project from a Maven archetype. It never completes successfully because of this error.

Comment: Just in case, I tried creating a sample project that uses common-lang, just to put the artifact in my local repo, but the jmh command line still fails.

Comment: I recommend to run the above command again but with redirecting it's output to a file like `mvn ... >x.log 2>&1` and check the output afterwards... Furthermore which Maven versions / JDK version are you running?

Comment: I have tested your command and get warnings like `[WARNING] Specified archetype not found.`...

Comment: Can you please try to use the following: `mvn archetype:generate -DinteractiveMode=false -DarchetypeGroupId=org.openjdk.jmh -DarchetypeArtifactId=jmh-java-benchmark-archetype -DgroupId=com.example -DartifactId=jmhBenchmarks -Dversion=1.23` ...

Comment: No change using that modified command line. I don't see that "not found" warning. All of my executions are in an Emacs shell buffer, and I've been examining the output each time. Using Maven 3.6.3 and Java 8.

Comment: Do you have some environment variables set for Maven like `M2_HOME` or something alike? If so please remove them and only put the `apache-3.6.3/bin` into your path nothing else.. Also try to execute on plain command not within any kind of tool (Neither in Emacs)... can you also please make a `mvn --version` and post this here...